# How to configure taglib with java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I got rid of web.xml and replaced it with 2 classes to configure the servlet environment.

```
public class UsersWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
```

and

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

My question is, how can I use one of these classes to configure the equivalent of a taglib declaration in the Web.xml?

e.g - how would I write this in java configuration?

```
<taglib>
  <taglib-uri>
    http://www.example.com/taglib
  </taglib-uri>
  <taglib-location>
    /taglib.tld
  </taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to configure anything. Since JSP 2.0 taglibs can be discovered automatically.

All You need to do is place them in WEB-INF or it's subfolders. If you are packaging Your TLDs as JAR files, place them in WEB-INF/lib or META-INF of the JAR